# Как скрыть стрелку в элементе Spinner?

Tags: java, android

На экране есть несколько элементов (например, spinner'ов), которые по нажатию на кнопку должны стать редактируемыми и наоборот. Как это можно провернуть с элементом `spinner`? Для того, чтобы поле просто стало нередактируемым, можно использовать `android:clickable="false"`. Таким образом, единственной проблемой остаются стрелочки. Как их скрыть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто: стрелочка указывается через фон элемента.
Замени фон своим, например прозрачным: android:background="#0000"

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:background="#0000" />
```

**update:**

Чтобы вернуть стрелку обратно (надо убрать свойство android:background="#0000"):

```
Drawable drawableOld = spinner.getBackground();
spinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    spinner.setBackground(drawableOld);
else
    spinner.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableOld);
```

Comment: Как вернуть стрелочку обратно? Если снова установить backgroud, то меняется цвет всего spinner'а.

Comment: PS Запомнить до изменения drawable и затем его снова поставить не получается т.к. minimum api стоит 15, а не 16.

Comment: Нет, так сделать нельзя. Обязательно надо на АПИ 15 и 16 одинаковый внешний вид.

Comment: Можно и нужно. Это не внешний вид, а смена названий функции (на самом деле та же самая функция)

Comment: Еще можно нарисовать свою стрелку (или поискать в ресурсах) и указать в background свой drawable xml со статусами.

Comment: Подробно по правильному способу: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/381-urok-163-grafika-drawable-bitmap-layer-list-state-list.html

Comment: Извиняюсь за свою невнимательность) Я не видел того что после else.